# dynamically selecting option values in option groups

Tags: javascript, dom, optgroup

How do i set the value of an option within an optgroup using DOM and vanilla javascript?  Since there are multiple values of A, how do i select 20/A vs 30/A? with...

```
document.getElementById('logphase').value = "A";
```

... which would be called at `window.onload`

```
<select id="logphase">
<optgroup label="10">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="20">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="30">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="40">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="D">D</option>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: `<option>` values must be unique

Comment: oh no, that is unfortunate.

Comment: If the optgroup labels matter enough to distinguish options that would otherwise mean the same thing, I would recommend adding the optgroup label (or some sort of unique optgroup identifier) to the beginning of each option value. For example, the value of the first option could be "20A".

Comment: great suggestion nicolas - that makes perfect sense.  Its one of those things staring you right in the face - thanks.